# Eager Loading - Only load Specific Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Quick question about eager loading. I have the following code:

> @user =
>   User.includes(:restaurants).find_by_unique_identifier(params[:unique_identifier])

However, I only want to load restaurants associated with a given user only if the restaurants have a list_id of X (which is one of the columns of the restaurants table).

How would I go about this?

I tried the following, but it still loaded all the restaurant records associated with the user.

```
@user = User.includes(:restaurants).where(:restaurants => {:list_id => params[:list_id]}).find_by_unique_identifier(params[:unique_identifier])
```

Comment: By the way, a user has_many restaurants and a restaurant has_many users through an associations join table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all the associations requirements setup, then you can use `joins`:

```
@user = User.all(:conditions =>["restaurants.list_id = ?", params[:list_id] ], :joins => [:restaurants])
```

**UPDATE:** 

*My code fetches a list of users. However, You can use your filtering methods to narrow down the list or get the individual records.*

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't look up the actual user. The user has to be found by looking him/her up through the unique_identifier that is assigned to each user. So first I want to find the user using this method and then pull in that particular user's restaurants, but only restaurants matching a given list_id.

Comment: Sorry if that sounds somewhat convoluted. Let me know if I can try to explain it better.

Comment: Why not adding another condition like: "AND id =?" then get the first item out of the list. This is a quick answer though...

Comment: Let's assume for example that you use my original code from above (so it has fetched all of the restaurant records) for that given user. How can I then refine that restaurant list to only be for the restaurants whose list_id matches a particular value?

Comment: Something like the following: @user_restaurants = @user.restaurants.where(:list_id => 1 ). I know that this is not the right code, but how could I properly write that?

Comment: Yeah...but I dont' endorse it either..Also note that ".first" method in rails is not a stable method...Always better to use ordering by "created_at" then get the first item (or last item). This way you are always sure that you are getting the right record.